# Artisan::call() in Test failing

Tags: phpunit, laravel, laravel-4

I need to clean the database before running the tests or I get weird errors about duplicate information.

in my PostTest.php file I create a setup method

```
public function setUp()
{
    Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
}
```

The phpunit tests then say:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Artisan' not found in C:\wamp\www\squigglemd\app\tests\PostTest.php on line 11
```

I've also tried:

```
\Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
```

How can I call Artisan from my tests?

Comment: You should simply call `parent::setUp()` since you're overriding this method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is how to call artisan from the test function when Artisan::call does not work.

```
    public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $app->make('artisan')->call('migrate:refresh');
    //Artisan::call('migrate:refresh'); // also works now too


}
```

Answer (score 2):

It`s better to use

```
public function setUp()
{   
    parent::setUp(); //this is reqired 

        Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
}
```

This is described in the docs

> Note: If you define your own setUp method within a test class, be sure to call parent::setUp.

see http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#introduction

Comment: It's the same thing just you are using the facade. (corrected the parent setup... this was also laravel 4 question)